# Twice Bash command substitution

Tags: linux, bash, variables, command-substitution

I have directories **a1..a5**, **b1..b5** and **c1..c5**. Inside each directory I have two files **a1**, **b1** and **c1**.

```
do mkdir /tmp/{a,b}$d; touch /tmp/{a,b,c}$d/{a,b,c}1; done;
```

I want to get all the files starting with 'a' or 'b' inside the directories starting with an 'a'. I can do it with:

```
DIRS=`ls -1 -d /tmp/{a,b}*/a*`
echo ${DIRS}
```

and obtain:

> /tmp/a1/a1 /tmp/a2/a1 /tmp/a3/a1 /tmp/a4/a1 /tmp/a5/a1 
>   /tmp/b1/a1 /tmp/b2/a1 /tmp/b3/a1 /tmp/b4/a1 /tmp/b5/a1

Now, I will use a variable called DATA to store the directories and later get the files:

```
DATA="/tmp/{a,b}*"
echo ${DATA}
DIRS=`ls -1 -d ${DATA}/a*`
echo ${DIRS}
```

In the output, the DATA contents is OK (**/tmp/{a,b}***), but I receive the following error:

> **ls: cannot access /tmp/{a,b}*/a*: No such file or directory**

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, but I can't find any reference about why my previous attempts failed.

```
DATA="/tmp/{a,b}*"
echo ${DATA}
DIRS=`eval "ls -1 -d ${DATA}/a*"`
echo ${DIRS}
```

**Output:**

> /tmp/a1/a1 /tmp/a2/a1 /tmp/a3/a1 /tmp/a4/a1 /tmp/a5/a1 /tmp/b1/a1
>   /tmp/b2/a1 /tmp/b3/a1 /tmp/b4/a1 /tmp/b5/a1

Comment: This happens because glob and brace expansion don't happen in double quotes or string assignments, while glob expansion does happen after word splitting. This means that if you do `echo something` vs `var=something; echo $var`, both will end up expanding globs but only the former will end up expanding braces.